# Rotate jpeg using ExifInterface doesn't work sometimes

Tags: android, rotation, jpeg

Hi this is how I rotate jpeg image:

```
private static boolean rotateJpg(String filepath, int degrees) {
    // get current rotation degree
    int iCurRotation = getExifOrientation(filepath);

    // create exif
    ExifInterface exif = null;

    try {
    exif = new ExifInterface(filepath);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    return false;
}

// Calculate new rotation degree
int iNewRotation = iCurRotation + degrees;

try {
    iNewRotation %= 360;
    if (iNewRotation < 0) iNewRotation += 360;

    int orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;
    switch (iNewRotation) {
    case 0:
        orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;
        break;
    case 90:
        orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90;
        break;
    case 180:
        orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180;
        break;
    case 270:
        orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270;
        break;
    }

    // save new rotation degree
    if (exif != null) {
        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, Integer.toString(orientation));
        exif.saveAttributes();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    return false;
}
return true;

}
```

Above code works. However, I sometimes get:

```
06-29 18:28:35.780: E/JHEAD(28163): Can't write back - didn't read all
```

I looked it up what it is and found out it's the external/jhead/jpgfile.c who's throwing the error:

```
// Command line parsing code
static const char * progname;   // program name for error messages

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Parse the marker stream until SOS or EOI is seen;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
static int ReadJpegSections (FILE * infile,ReadMode_t ReadMode)
{
    int a;
    int HaveCom = FALSE;

    a = fgetc(infile);


    if (a != 0xff || fgetc(infile) != M_SOI){
        return FALSE;
    }
    for(;SectionsRead < MAX_SECTIONS-1;){
        int itemlen;
        int marker = 0;
        int ll,lh, got;
        uchar * Data;

        for (a=0;a<7;a++){
            marker = fgetc(infile);
            if (marker != 0xff) break;

            if (a >= 6){

                printf("too many padding bytes\n");

                return FALSE;

            }
        }

        if (marker == 0xff){
            // 0xff is legal padding, but if we get that many, something's wrong.
            ErrExit("too many padding bytes!");
        }

        Sections[SectionsRead].Type = marker;

        // Read the length of the section.
        lh = fgetc(infile);
        ll = fgetc(infile);

        itemlen = (lh << 8) | ll;

        if (itemlen < 2){
            ErrExit("invalid marker");
        }

        Sections[SectionsRead].Size = itemlen;

        Data = (uchar *)malloc(itemlen+1); // Add 1 to allow sticking a 0 at the end.
        if (Data == NULL){
            ErrExit("Could not allocate memory");
        }
        Sections[SectionsRead].Data = Data;

        // Store first two pre-read bytes.
        Data[0] = (uchar)lh;
        Data[1] = (uchar)ll;

        got = fread(Data+2, 1, itemlen-2, infile); // Read the whole section.
        if (got != itemlen-2){
            ErrExit("reading from file");
        }
        SectionsRead += 1;

        //printf("Marker '%x' size %d\n",marker, itemlen);
        switch(marker){

            case M_SOS:   // stop before hitting compressed data 
                // If reading entire image is requested, read the rest of the data.
                if (ReadMode & READ_IMAGE){
                    int cp, ep, size;
                    // Determine how much file is left.
                    cp = ftell(infile);
                    fseek(infile, 0, SEEK_END);
                    ep = ftell(infile);
                    fseek(infile, cp, SEEK_SET);

                    size = ep-cp;
                    Data = (uchar *)malloc(size);
                    if (Data == NULL){
                        ErrExit("could not allocate data for entire image");
                    }

                    got = fread(Data, 1, size, infile);
                    if (got != size){
                        ErrExit("could not read the rest of the image");
                    }

                    Sections[SectionsRead].Data = Data;
                    Sections[SectionsRead].Size = size;
                    Sections[SectionsRead].Type = PSEUDO_IMAGE_MARKER;
                    SectionsRead ++;
                    HaveAll = 1;
                }
                return TRUE;

            case M_EOI:   // in case it's a tables-only JPEG stream
                printf("No image in jpeg!\n");
                return FALSE;

            case M_COM: // Comment section
                if (HaveCom || ((ReadMode & READ_EXIF) == 0)){
                    // Discard this section.
                    free(Sections[--SectionsRead].Data);
                }else{
                    process_COM(Data, itemlen);
                    HaveCom = TRUE;
                }
                break;

            case M_JFIF:
                // Regular jpegs always have this tag, exif images have the exif
                // marker instead, althogh ACDsee will write images with both markers.
                // this program will re-create this marker on absence of exif marker.

                free(Sections[--SectionsRead].Data);
                break;

            case M_EXIF:

                if (SectionsRead <= 2){
                    // Seen files from some 'U-lead' software with Vivitar scanner
                    // that uses marker 31 later in the file (no clue what for!)
                    process_EXIF((char *)Data, itemlen);
                }else{
                    // Discard this section.
                    free(Sections[--SectionsRead].Data);
                }
                break;

            case M_SOF0: 
            case M_SOF1: 
            case M_SOF2: 
            case M_SOF3: 
            case M_SOF5: 
            case M_SOF6: 
            case M_SOF7: 
            case M_SOF9: 
            case M_SOF10:
            case M_SOF11:
            case M_SOF13:
            case M_SOF14:
            case M_SOF15:
                process_SOFn(Data, marker);
                break;
            default:
                // Skip any other unknown sections.
                if (ShowTags){
                    printf("Unknown Jpeg section marker 0x%02x size %d\n",marker, itemlen);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Discard read data.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
void DiscardData(void)
{
    int a;
    for (a=0;a<SectionsRead;a++){
        free(Sections[a].Data);
    }
    memset(&ImageInfo, 0, sizeof(ImageInfo));
    SectionsRead = 0;
    HaveAll = 0;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Read image data.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
int ReadJpegFile(const char * FileName, ReadMode_t ReadMode)
{
    FILE * infile;
    int ret;

    infile = fopen(FileName, "rb"); // Unix ignores 'b', windows needs it.

    if (infile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: can't open '%s'\n", progname, FileName);
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Scan the JPEG headers.
    ret = ReadJpegSections(infile, ReadMode);
    if (!ret){
        printf("Not JPEG: %s\n",FileName);
    }

    fclose(infile);

    if (ret == FALSE){
        DiscardData();
    }
    return ret;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Write image data back to disk.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
void WriteJpegFile(const char * FileName)
{
    FILE * outfile;
    int a;

    if (!HaveAll){
        ErrExit("Can't write back - didn't read all");
    }

    outfile = fopen(FileName,"wb");
    if (outfile == NULL){
        ErrExit("Could not open file for write");
    }

    // Initial static jpeg marker.
    fputc(0xff,outfile);
    fputc(0xd8,outfile);

    if (Sections[0].Type != M_EXIF && Sections[0].Type != M_JFIF){
        // The image must start with an exif or jfif marker.  If we threw those away, create one.
        static uchar JfifHead[18] = {
            0xff, M_JFIF,
            0x00, 0x10, 'J' , 'F' , 'I' , 'F' , 0x00, 0x01, 
            0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x2C, 0x01, 0x2C, 0x00, 0x00 
        };
        fwrite(JfifHead, 18, 1, outfile);
    }

    // Write all the misc sections
    for (a=0;a<SectionsRead-1;a++){
        fputc(0xff,outfile);
        fputc(Sections[a].Type, outfile);
        fwrite(Sections[a].Data, Sections[a].Size, 1, outfile);
    }

    // Write the remaining image data.
    fwrite(Sections[a].Data, Sections[a].Size, 1, outfile);

    fclose(outfile);
}
```

I get above error at line:

```
exif.saveAttributes();
```

It's very inconsistent to get this error. Also it's not even catchable on try/catch(Exception).
How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to pare that down to the bits that are at least relevant to your question...

Comment: Happens to me too, no idea :-/